# Make undo button in recoil js

Tags: reactjs, undo, recoiljs

I am looking for implementing undo button, on my projects using recoil as state management, and i see [this documentation](https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/atom-effects/#history-example), but i am not sure how to implement it.

Can anyone tell me how to implement that undo functionality in real project (with code examples)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for undo functionality. I wrote it in functional components.

It is just an example

```
const [timeline, setTimeline] = useState([]);
const [loads, setLoads] = useState([]);
const [undo, setUndo] = useState([]);
const [redo, setRedo] = useState([]);

const latestData = (newTimeline, newLoads) => {
  setTimeline([...newTimeline]);
  setLoads([...newLoads]);

  const newUndo = {
    timeline: [...newTimeline],
    loads: [...newLoads],
  };

  setUndo([...undo, ...newUndo]);
}

const undoChanges = () => {
  const prevChange = undo[undo.length - 1];
  const copyOfUndo = [...undo];

  setRedo([...undo]);

  timeline([...prevChange.timeline]);
  loads([...prevChange.loads]);

  prevChange.pop();
  undo([...prevChange]);
}
```

Comment: So how to do something like this in recoil js